# Make POST API call from Google Sheets to Hubspot with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, post, hubspot-api

I need to create marketing events (like webinar data) in Hubspot taking data from cells in Google Sheets. Marketing events are inside Contacts -> Contacts -> Marketing events.
Here is Hubspot API documentation on marketing events https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/marketing/marketing-events

I failed to get a request so far.

Here is what I did:

1. First I created a «private app» under may account and took its token, this is how they do now as API keys are going to be deprecated soon.

For now while I test I allowed all possibles scopes in this app.

2. I took the number of the account from the URL https://app-eu1.hubspot.com/private-apps/NUMBER (8 digit number)
3. I tried some endpoints and here might be a mistake, from all documentation it’s not obvious which endpoint to take in my case. For now I use this (took it from documentation) var url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/marketing-events/attendance/NUMBER//email-create';

Then goes my code in Google Apps Script:

```
//loads data to Hubspot
function loadData(email,eventName,startDateTime,timeEvent,type,eventOrganizer,subscriberState) {

var url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/marketing-events/attendance/NUMBER//email-create';

var body = {
"email": email,
"eventName": eventName, 
"startDateTime": startDateTime, 
"timeEvent": timeEvent, 
"type": type, 
"eventOrganizer": eventOrganizer, 
"subscriberState":subscriberState
}

var option = {
  "muteHttpExceptions" :true,
  "method":"POST",
  'payload': body,
  "headers": {
      "authorization": ’TOKEN’,
      "content-type": "application/json"
  }
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option); 
}
```

Please advise what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

From `I need to create marketing events (like webinar data) in Hubspot taking data from cells in Google Sheets` and your showing request body, when I saw your provided document, it seems that the endpoint is `POST /marketing/v3/marketing-events/events` which is not `POST /marketing/v3/marketing-events/attendance/{externalEventId}/{subscriberState}/email-create`. It seems that your endpoint is for

If you wanted to use "Marketing Events", from your provided official document, I found a sample curl command as follows.

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/marketing-events/events \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "eventName": "string",
  "eventType": "string",
  "startDateTime": "2022-12-16T00:51:15.731Z",
  "endDateTime": "2022-12-16T00:51:15.731Z",
  "eventOrganizer": "string",
  "eventDescription": "string",
  "eventUrl": "string",
  "eventCancelled": true,
  "customProperties": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "value": "string",
      "timestamp": 0,
      "sourceId": "string",
      "sourceLabel": "string",
      "source": "IMPORT",
      "selectedByUser": true,
      "selectedByUserTimestamp": 0,
      "sourceVid": [
        0
      ],
      "sourceMetadata": "string",
      "requestId": "string",
      "updatedByUserId": 0,
      "persistenceTimestamp": 0
    }
  ],
  "externalAccountId": "string",
  "externalEventId": "string"
}'
```

When this is converted to Google Apps Script, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
var url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/marketing-events/attendance/NUMBER//email-create';
```

#### To:

```
var url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/marketing-events/events';
```

And also,

#### From:

```
var option = {
  "muteHttpExceptions" :true,
  "method":"POST",
  'payload': body,
  "headers": {
      "authorization": ’TOKEN’,
      "content-type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
var option = {
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "method": "POST",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(body),
  "headers": { "authorization": "Bearer " + "###YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN###" },
  "contentType": "application/json"
}
```

#### Note:

- If you are required to use your currently showing endpoint of `var url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/marketing-events/attendance/NUMBER//email-create';`, it is required to modify your request body as follows. Please be careful about this.

  ```bash
  curl --request POST \
    --url https://api.hubapi.com/marketing/v3/marketing-events/attendance///email-create \
    --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --data '{
    "inputs": [
      {
        "interactionDateTime": 0,
        "properties": {
          "additionalProp1": "string",
          "additionalProp2": "string",
          "additionalProp3": "string"
        },
        "email": "string",
        "contactProperties": {
          "additionalProp1": "string",
          "additionalProp2": "string",
          "additionalProp3": "string"
        }
      }
    ]
  }'
  ```

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Marketing Events on Document of API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/marketing/marketing-events)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike you are right. I also found out from their support that external event ID should be from external software and not a random ID but we don't use software so decided to create events manually and then update attendees autommatically.